# Eclipse, SVN error after updating SVN.connector 2.2.2

Tags: php, eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-3.6

Eclipse for PHP Developers

Version: Helios Service Release 2

Build id:20110301-1815

Mac OsX 10.6.6 (all updates installed)

I updated my Eclipse SVN connector to the most current version (using the Eclipse updater).
The new plugin file names are:
org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.svnkit16_2.2.2.I20110318-1700.jar
org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector_2.2.2.I20110318-1700.jar

After updating I cannot *commit* or *update* any of my projects with any SVN server any more (tried using different servers). The error message I get during committing is:

*Some of selected resources were not added to version control.
svn: Error while dispatching event: org.eclipse.team.svn.core.connector.ISVNProgressMonitor$ItemState.(Ljava/lang/String;IILjava/lang/String;IIJLjava/lang/String;)V*

Beside that I am still able to browse the SVN Repositories

any help is highly appreciated!
Thanks
Pascal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, everything is working again.

I uninstalled all existing SVN plugins (to find in the menu under Help/Install New Software/ and then in the bottom right corner "What is already installed".) In that menu uninstall all SVN related plugins, restart Eclipse and start over again with installing a fresh SVN.

NOTE: All SVN Repositories and Project Versions did still exist after I reinstalled everything.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manual add / enable this software site in "Available Sites" preferences window.

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/0.7/update-site/

After update SVN connector should work properly.

Comment: Hi Tomasz, I added the "Site" and indeed there were new updates available. After downloading and installing I restarted and got prompted with the option to choose the "SVN Connector". After selecting the SVN Kit 1.3.5 I get an error message telling me that the connector is already installed. Tried uninstall and reinstall, but keep getting the same issue. When I look into my preferences under "team/SVN" there is not SNV connector available in the drop down. Any more ideas?